# Can I hide request information from the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

I am building an application using ASP.NET MVC 3. At one point, on going from one page to another, my URL looks like this:

```
/Employee/EntityHome/15
```

where 15 is the ID passed. Is there any way out not to show it in the URL request?

Comment: Pass `15` as a POST parameter to `/Employee/EntityHome` controller.

Comment: @rook You should post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If MVC is  capable  of  using  post instead of  get then use post.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `15` as a POST parameter to `/Employee/EntityHome` controller, for example in web page you can do the following AJAX request (via `jQuery`):

```js
function send_employee_id(value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<your webapp>/Employee/EntityHome',
    data: { 'id' : value },
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    async: false,
    success: function(html) {
      // whatever on success
    });
}
```

Catch it in your MVC app controller POST parameters container, as parameter with 'id'  name and do something.

Also you could try classic HTML forms to post data:

```html
<form action="/Employee/EntityHome" method="post">
   . . .
   <input type="hidden" name="id" />
   . . .
</form>
```

(in this case, see parameter with `id` name in `EntityHome` controller POST data container)

For your ASP.MVC app, in controller `Employee` use method `EntityHome` to grab POST paramer:

```asp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EntityHome(string id)
{
  var employeeId = id;
  . . .
}
```